# Golang Sessions Working but need to authenticate route based on if value exist

Tags: go, session

I am trying to get sessions working on my api.

I want to be able to define certain endpoints as restricted, which would need the user to be logged in to access them. And I also want to be able to get specific information just for the user that logged in, to prevent others from getting information that is not theirs.

I have registration working, which saves the user to the mongodb collection.

I have sign in working where it checks if the user provided password and the password hash from the users collection match.

Now I am creating a session for the user that is returned.

Here is where I am getting a little confused, in my default endpoint ("/") I am trying to test getting the session restriction working.

Would it also be possible to create a middleware to check if authenticated that I could just add to specific endpoints to not have to duplicate code.

Currently when creating the session I am setting:

```
sess.Values["id"] = existingUser.ID.String()
```

So that I can use the user id to query user specific information from the collection (is this secure?)

Here is my code:

When configuring the middleware at top level:

```
e.Use(session.Middleware(sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("secret"))))
```

When signing in:

```
err = bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(existingUser.HashedPassword), []byte(signInUser.Password))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return c.String(http.StatusNotAcceptable, "Incorrect password")
}

// create the session
sess, err := session.Get("session", c)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return err
}
sess.Options = &sessions.Options{
    Path:     "/",
    MaxAge:   86400 * 7,
    HttpOnly: true,
}
sess.Values["id"] = existingUser.ID.String()
sess.Save(c.Request(), c.Response())

return c.String(http.StatusAccepted, "Signed In!")
```

The default / route:

```
e.GET("/", func(c echo.Context) error {
    sess, err := session.Get("session", c)
    if err != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusForbidden, "Access Denied")
    }

    if sess.Values["id"] == nil || sess.Values["id"] == "" {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusForbidden, "Access Denied 2")
    }

    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, sess.Values["id"])
})
```

Comment: So your code is working... you just want someone to give you a stamp of approval that it's good? The session data is stored on your server and retrieved when the user sends the right session cookie, so in that sense it's secure. Yes, you can make a middleware that you can apply to a specific route.

Comment: But if someone knows the user id can they somehow forge the session cookie?

Comment: The session cookie is just a randomly generated id. Your server keeps track of that id and links it to the specific data you chose to store for that id. The only way to "forge a session cookie" is to steal one that has already been created by your server. The client can't create a session. The data stored in your session is server-side only.

Comment: Looks like you're using github.com/gorilla/sessions. In that case the cookie is encrypted and authenticated, and security depends entirely on the quality of your encryption keys.